# Firefox doesn't show texts

Tags: firefox, fonts

My Firefox doesn't show text on some sites, such as Google:

[image: screenshot]

I use Firefox 29 and Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: Are you using Ambiance the default theme?

Comment: Yes, I am using default theme

Comment: When did this start to happen? Did you try to reset your firefox profile `help`>`troubleshooting info`>`reset firefox`

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't show yet

Comment: so when did this happen? did you change anything or apply?

Comment: go to `browser settings` as in `edit`>`preferences`>`content`>`advanced` and uncheck the box that allows other programs to choose the fonts for the page and use the fonts that I choose.

Comment: No, I didn't any special actions.

Comment: ok, I'm glad it worked. That means you might have installed an app or extension that involves with text in firefox. I'll convert this an answer so this question won't stay open.

Comment: I think even better solution is to repair your system fonts, just do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig fontconfig-config` It helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We happened to provide the solution this way:

Go to `browser settings` as in `edit`>`preferences`>`content`>`advanced` and uncheck the box that allows other programs to choose the fonts for the page and use the fonts that I choose.

Comment: as an alternative one may try to repair system fonts with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig fontconfig-config` It solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is a poor solution, as one usually wants the website to be able to choose fonts. Sometimes the fonts are symbols, and without them the webpage is ugly / unreadable / etc.